# How do I disable my GPU so that it defaults to the integrated graphics?

Tags: gpu, integrated-graphics

I have an old computer that is experiencing graphical related corruption as well as randomly restarting.

In an attempt to isolate the problem I want to disable the GPU so it reverts to the chipset inbuilt into the motherboard.

I have tried disabling the GPU in the device manager, but it still requires that I plug my monitor into the GPUs monitor output port, which seems to indicate to me that it isn't truly disabled.

How would I go about disabling it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to disable it in the BIOS. They vary between companies and models so I can't give you a definite location, but it will be in the section for video.

Answer (score 10):

Pull it out of the motherboard, perhaps? Can't get more disabled than that, and there's no chance of the OS interfering before it's had a chance to realise that no, it shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 3):

Check for "Primary display device" or something to that effect in the BIOS. Usualy you'll have options like On Board, PCI, PCI Express or AGP.

Answer (score 0):

The bios probably has an option to select the default video device, just check to see that is isn't PCI-E, you can also plug the monitor into the onboard graphics and completely remove the GPU

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide specifics on how the author solves their problem